# Filter associative rows in a 2d array using another 2d array which does not contain all columns

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, array-intersect

I'm using `array_intersect` for comparing two 2d arrays.

```
$myArray = array(
  array(
    'site_id'  => 'S6407', 
    'tssr_id'  => 'TSSRBOQ-200204-0145-59'
  ),
  array(
    'site_id'  => 'S5910', 
    'tssr_id'  => 'TSSRBOQ-200204-0145-8'
  ),
);

// $items_tssr is get from another variable
foreach ($items_tssr as $key => $value) {
    $array_validate[] = array(
        'site_id' => $value['site_id'],
        'tssr_id' => $value['no_tssr_boq_site']
    );
}

$result = array_map(
    'unserialize',
    array_intersect(
        array_map('serialize', $myArray),
        array_map('serialize', $array_validate)
    )
);
// if there are same 
if (array_key_exists(0, $result) {
    echo 'process this';
} else {
    echo 'dont process this';
}
```

My problem is that the original `$myArray` contains more columns than just 'site_id' and 'tssr_id'.

```
$myArray_origin = array(
    'site_id' => 'S6407',
    'tssr_id'  => 'TSSRBOQ-200204-0145-59'
    'site_name' => 'Site S6407',
    'id_site_doc'=> '127361,
    'implementation_id' => 'imp4121',
    'status' => "implementation_created",
    "endstate" => false
),
...
```

How do I filter the `$myArray_origin` array without throwing away a few of the values? `$array_validate` only contains 2 columns of data: 'site_id' and 'tssr_id'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/array_filter) + [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/in_array) instead. This will only keep the entries whose `site_id` and `tssr_id` are present in one of `array_validate`'s own entries:

```
$result = array_filter($myArray, function (array $entry) use ($array_validate): bool {
  return in_array([
    'site_id' => $entry['site_id'], 
    'tssr_id' => $entry['tssr_id']
  ], $array_validate, true);
});
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/4Qhmr**

Comment: thank you, i remove `: bool` cause i used php 5.6
how can i get the array does not pass?

Comment: Do you mean, how to get all the other entries (those that don't match)?

Comment: Just replace `in_array` with `!in_array` (if you don't want to repeat it, you can replace `array_filter` with a loop and a `if` / `else`).

Answer (score 0):

If the columns in the validate array are "known in advance by the developer" (like in Jeto's solution), then a native function is available -- `array_uintersect()`. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/8D8vq)

```
var_export(
    array_uintersect(
        $array,
        $validate,
        fn($a, $b) =>
            [$a['site_id'], $a['tssr_id']]
            <=>
            [$b['site_id'], $b['tssr_id']]
    )
);
```

If the columns are not known in advance, then iterated function calls will be necessary. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/aYXsM)

```
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        function($row) use ($validate) {
            foreach ($validate as $filter) {
                if (!array_diff_assoc($filter, $row)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    )
);
```

Caution, keep data types in mind if you are going to make strict comparisons.  [For example](https://3v4l.org/avs6n), `false` is loosely equal to `null`.

For maximum reliability with strict comparisons expect greater code length. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/jEir6)

```
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        function($row) use ($validate) {
            foreach ($validate as $filter) {
                foreach ($filter as $k => $v) {
                    if (!key_exists($k, $row) || $row[$k] !== $v) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    )
);
```

Making associative comparisons between two 2d arrays is not going to be a highly performant operation.  If you find yourself in this situation, try to refactor your code to make key-based comparisons on one or both of the payloads.  Lookup arrays serve as great tools for optimizing filtering operations because PHP is very fast while checking for the existence of keys.